# TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds() alternative?

Tags: java, time

I'm looking to convert an arbitrary value from milliseconds to seconds and my first choice was TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds. However it returns a long and so converts 1 millisecond to 0 seconds instead of 0.001 seconds.

When reading [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) I can sort of extract that the TimeUnit is specifically meant to go "the other way". Even though I do not understand why they chose this strategy, I'm looking for an (lazy!) alternative that can do this type of conversions.

Comment: Voting to close as primarily opinion based, we can't guess at the decisions made by the API designers. However to me `long` seems a more logical choice than `int` for example, and given the intention of use (eg with `Object.wait(long)`) a floating point number is not logical; however those are only guesses and not a factual answer.

Comment: In these day of 64-bit processors, it wouldn't save anything to use `int` but you can get overflows for using and `int` (or even a long in extreme cases)

Comment: I understand choosing a long as return value when moving to "finer" units (e.g. from seconds to milliseconds), but when converting the other way (e.g. from milliseconds to seconds) this does not make sense to me. I'll update my question.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Agreed, although if there is any information on this particular decision I'm interested. I changed the question to reflect what I really need.

Comment: @Timo First of all the methods are defined on enum level, so they equally apply to `DAYS` as to `MILLISECONDS` (eg `TimeUnit.DAYS.toSeconds(250000)` is larger than `int`), second for example `TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(Long.MAX_VALUE)` will overflow when you'd use an `int`, finally it provides consistency of interface (eg using all the same types).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel See updated question. I understand overflows and why it should be a long. I understand that given the current implementation you will get the a long for every conversion when calling `toSeconds`. I might have caused some misunderstanding with the way I posed the question, that is why I changed it (considerably) to reflect what I need for my program. If you know a conversion utility that does return decimal values, I'd be grateful!

Answer (score 3):

well, I think they've tried to cover the "worst case". For example, if you try to convert 1 day into nanos, the number will be larger than the max integer

```
System.out.println(TimeUnit.DAYS.toNanos(1)); //86400000000000
System.out.println(Integer.MAX_VALUE);        //21474836477
```

But I agree somehow that numbers can get even bigger than the max long integer in extreme situations. At least the javadoc warns the user about that.

Comment: Thanks! Given the discussion above I have changed my question. Would you know a good alternative conversion tool?

Comment: if performance is not an issue, I think you could just get the current implementation and replace long with bigdecimals

Comment: Do you have any experience with javax.measure (or JScience which is the reference impl.)?